# rails has_many and has_many :through error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code in `family_service` model:

```
has_many :families_users
has_many :users, :through => :families_users
```

But when trying to execute in a loop (service is a family_service)

```
users << service.users
```

I get this error

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughOrderError in Budgets#index

Cannot have a has_many :through association 'FamilyService#users'
which goes through 'FamilyService#families_users' before the through association is defined.
```

But as you can see, it **is** defined as it should be.

Comment: The code here does not actually constitute a verifyable example that reproduces the behavior your talking about so we can't see that "it is defined as it should be".  The problem here is not in the code provided and is most likely due to human error such as running the wrong code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

After a big effort, I found that I have this line before the lines in the question:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :families_users
```

So this line actually uses a :`join_table` which is equal to `:through` before the actual line of `has_many :families_users`.

That's why I got the error.

Hopefully someone that is upgrading to rails 5 will find this handy.